# Erro na inicialização do Nignx: ngx_master_520 the event was not signaled for 5s

Tags: nginx, openssl

Estou tentando configurar um certificado SSL no meu servidor web que utiliza Windows 2008 RC2 e Nginx. Sempre me deparo com um erro no arquivo de log e isso faz com que o Nginx não execute. O erro é:

> Error in initializing Nignx: ngx_master_520 the event was not signaled for 5s

O arquivo `nginx.conf` está configurado como abaixo:

```
server {
   listen 443; 
   ssl on; 
   ssl_certificate c: /nginx/ssl/SSL.pem; 
   ssl_certificate_key c: /nginx/ssl/privatekey.key; 

   server_name localhost; 
   location / {
     root html; 
     index index.html; 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Carlos, isso acontece com certa frequência, tanto que tem uma razão de *off-topic* específica. Só por curiosidade sobre a UI/UX: você passou de um site pro outro e não se deu conta? Qual o motivo da confusão?

Comment: Tens a `passphrase` no teu certificado? Costuma ser a origem desse teu erro. Removendo a `passphrase` do certificado deverá solucionar. [(Como remover Inglês)](http://mnx.io/blog/removing-a-passphrase-from-an-ssl-key/)

Comment: @brasofilo é que antes eu já possuia uma conta no site em inglês e quando fui postar devo ter clicado para ir a versão em português, eu não sabia desta versão.

Comment: @Zuul no certificado tem sim passphrase, andei pesquisando mas não encontrei como gerar o arquivo .CSR sem passphrase mas não encontrei.

Comment: @CarlosAndrade Vê aqui, está em Inglês mas tem os comandos para o tipo de certificado que referiste: [Generating a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)](http://linux.about.com/od/ubusrv_doc/a/ubusg25t12.htm).

Comment: @Zuul a solução com certeza seria esta. Agora só estou me esbarrando em como executar o Nginx sem o passphrase, pois utilizo Windows Server 2008 RC2. Encontrei vários artigos mas somente sobre o Linux.

Comment: @CarlosAndrade Com o certificado sem a `passphrase`  que erro estás a ter?